# How to receive and Split an array of objects in C# .NET Web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, datatables, controller

I've got an imported excel file on the front end which, on save, sends the excel data as an array of objects to our `.NET Web API` controller via `[FromBody]`, which in turn sends this data to a SQL `stored procedure` via a `DataTable`. Each object in the array is one row from the excel file.

**EDIT** My data is being sent from the front end via a `POST` with `httpOptions` `body:` . The data sent to the controller looks like:

```
[
{name: "Bob", position: "Software Developer", sales: 100000}
 {name: "Ted", position: "Software Developer", sales: 100568}
 {name: "George", position: "Software Developer", sales: 40000}
]
```

In the `C#` controller, how can I receive this array with an unknown number of objects and use it? Currently I'm using an example `forEach` block which originally only accepted an array of ID's, but this doesn't work as now I'm trying to send an array of objects and I can't use `.split` on it:

```
[Route("api/myRoute")]
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> uploadExcelData
                (
                  [FromBody] Array excelRows
    )
            {
                 string[] aryExcelRowsObjects;

                 DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                 dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(string)));
                 dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("position", typeof(string)));
                 dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("sales", typeof(int)));

                 // this is the example I'm using and it no longer works as you can't use .Split() on an array. What should I change it to?
                 aryExcelRowsObjects = excelRows.Split(','); 

                // this is the example I'm using and I don't think it accounts for adding multiple columns into a row
                    foreach (string s in aryExcelRowsObjects)
                    {
                        dataTable.Rows.Add(s);
                    }

            }
```

What should I change in the two sections with code comments?

Comment: Your controller is still looking for a string.

Comment: What does your data look like?  Is it really just a string?  If so, what format (for example, is it like a stream of CSV data?  Is it JSON?

Comment: The question that remains here, if you are sending an entire set of rows, how are you representing each of the rows as a JSON? Why are you attempting to deserialize a multitude of rows as a simple string? How are you visualizing the mapping between the JSON and the deserialized string?

Comment: Exelrows is empty because of sending a simple string.

Comment: @SaiGummaluri I've updated my question. I don't think I'm using JSON, rather I'm sending the data as-is via POST httpOptions body:`

Comment: You can't just change the data you're sending back and expect it to get properly bound to a string. You need to deal with the fact you have an array of objects.

Comment: @KyleVassella - Since you are triggering `POST` using the HttpOptions itself, you can set the body to be an array of objects. Each of these objects is an excel row. However, the array should be comma separated (which isnt the case in your snippet shared). On the server side, you can create a class with the three properties matching the properties on your client side and let webapi itself do the job of deserializing it for you. The endpoint can be receiving `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is your `C#` representation of the excel row.

Comment: You need to understand what your data looks like in order to use it.  If it looks like `"R1C1, R1C2[new-line]R2C1, R2C2"` (where RnCm represents Row n, Column m), then you can take it in as a string and use a CSV parser.  If it looks like JSON, use a JSON parser, if it's XML, an XML parser.  If you don't know what it looks like, find that out first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Recently worked on same scenario you need to get a list of objects.

```
public class Employee
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Position { get; set; }
public int Sales { get; set; }
}
```

For Controller

```
    [Route("api/myRoute")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> uploadExcelData([FromBody] List<Employee> EmpList){
    EmpList.ForEach(Emp=> {
    ...............Write your Code
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The data types you have don't line up so the array you're sending back now can't be bound to a string so `excelRows` is null. So, when you try to split `excelRows`, it blows up in your face.

Have your controller accept the data you're sending...

Let's say you're sending back `Employee[]`.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Sales { get; set; }
}
```

Now, obviously you can't call `string.Split` on `Employee[]`. But you can do whatever is available to `[]` like a `for`, `foreach`, `Select`, and so on.

```
foreach(var employee in employees)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: I understand that this is the problem, but I don't know how to fix it. I've just edited the code above to accept an array, but what should I use to parse through each object in the array instead of .split()?

Comment: @KyleVassella: you get an collection of strongly typed objects.  In ChiefTwoPencils' foreach loop, you can type `employee.Position` and see that particular employee's position.  Simlilarly, `employee.Sales` will give you his/her sales as an integer.  The ASP.NET plumbing will convert the JSON you are uploading into that collection for you automatically, as long as everything matches up.

Comment: Thanks @ChiefTwoPencils and Flydog. Chief, how would I resolve your public Employee class with my `[FromBody] Array excelRows` line of code? It seems the excelRows array I get via [FromBody] needs to be matched to this Employee class you've created, but I'm unsure how to go about this. With [FromBody] I'm importing an array of objects, but your employee class represents one row (object) in the excelRows array.

Comment: @KyleVassella, I assume you have control over the code so just implement my `Employee` class and have your endpoint signature be: `uploadExcelData([FromBody] Employee[] excelRows)`.